# iOS Xcode 8.3 Facebook SDK login Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-login

Everytime I try and login with Facebook recently it doesn't work and it shows the error below. This happens in the iOS Simulator and on an actual Device.

`2017-04-27 10:18:04.361 Colour Confuse[43796:1851249] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2017-04-27 10:18:04.362 Colour Confuse[43796:1851249] Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2017-04-27 10:18:04.363 Colour Confuse[43796:1851249] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"`

It shows the ViewController to allow the User to login, however when I click to continue it throws the following error and then the view goes blank. If I then press 'Done' to close the FB View Controller it crashed the app completely.

`Facebook login was cancelled by user.
2017-04-27 10:18:07.346 Colour Confuse[43796:1851249] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2017-04-27 10:18:07.346 Colour Confuse[43796:1851249] Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2017-04-27 10:18:07.347 Colour Confuse[43796:1851249] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2017-04-27 10:18:07.876 Colour Confuse[43796:1851249] Warning: Attempt to present <FBSDKContainerViewController: 0x7fe74da048c0> on <Colour_Confuse.GameViewController: 0x7fe74db02d80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

It's been working fine until a couple of days ago and I just have no clue as to why it's suddently stopped working as I haven't changed anything.

```
let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "user_friends", "public_profile"], from: self.view?.window?.rootViewController) { (result, error) in
        if result?.isCancelled == true {
            self.fbLoginError()
        } else if error == nil {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: (result?.token.tokenString)!)
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error:Error?) in
                if error == nil {
                    print("FB and Firebase Login Successful")

                    })
                } else {
                    print(error)
                    self.fbLoginError()
                }
            })
        } else {
            print(error)
            self.fbLoginError()
        }
    }
```

AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdates(onAccessTokenChange: true)

    FIRApp.configure()

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}


    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()

}
```

It never hits any of the if statements and just ignores everything within the completion closure.

I also have KeyChain Sharing enabled

PLIST

[image: PLIST]

Comment: Can you show some code what you had try out

Comment: can you show the plist file

Comment: i think you forget to implement this method in appdelegate class func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

Comment: i update my answer or you can follow this one also http://www.appcoda.com/firebase-facebook-login/

Comment: @Ryann did you got you answer I am facing same issue today onward Facebook login not working yesterday everything was working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try like this!

**Appdelegate.swift**

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      FIRApp.configure()
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    return handled
}
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) { 
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
 }
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
  @IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: UIButton) {
    let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to login: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current() else {
            print("Failed to get access token")
            return
        }

        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)

        // Perform login by calling Firebase APIs
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(okayAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return
            }

            // Present the main view
            if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainView") {
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        })
    }   
}
```

**Info.plist**
Insert the following XML snippet

```
 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb1249988161716400</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>1249988161716400</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>YourString</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Hi, i\m running this from an SKScene. it has been working fine for months . only yesterday is when it stopped working. After implementing the code above it\s still throwing the same errors and warnings.

Comment: @Ryann786 which code you implement so it was not working from yesterday

Comment: The only difference I made was I logged out of my app and back in to test new users again and it didn't work however I hadn't changed any of the login Code.

Comment: The only other thing I did was update the FB SKD from 4.21.0 to 4.22.0 using cocoapods

Comment: I have reverted my project back to when i first updated to fbskd 4.22.0 and the issue was happening then. I guess there is an issue with his release.

Comment: @Ryann786, how did you downgrade the FBSDK? Or for that matter, how do you know which version you have installed?